# $event object being passed is undefined in Angular version 1.5

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-ng-change

I have this dropdown component that allows for filtering, I recently upgraded from Angular 1.3 to 1.5. I'm not able to figure out why my $event object is undefined in the ng-change and ng-keypress:

Here is my template:

```
<input id="inputElement" type="text" class="form-control no-select" name="inputField" ng-change="ctrl.filterTextChangeLocal($event)"
ng-model="ctrl.ngModelValue" ng-click="ctrl.openDropdown($event)" 
ng-keydown="ctrl.onKeyboardPressed($event = $event)" />
```

Here is my controller:

```
public filterTextChangeLocal($event: ng.IAngularEvent)
{
   $event // comes up undefined
   // other code like $event.which breaks because $event is undefined
}
```

It was previously working so I'm not sure why it is not anymore. The click $event works fine. Thanks for the help.

Comment: This looks like typescript.  Does it still compile with the latest type definitions or have they changed?

Comment: Yeah it is. I looked into that and some have changed, but the $event seems to be the same. The down, up arrows, enter, space bars all work fine to navigate the list in the onKeyboardPressed function.